# Issue with Twilio Redirect tag

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-voice

This is such a basic thing and I remember i have had it working before. Not sure what im missing but redirect tag doesn't seem to be working and instead i hear the url played out in test to speech. Below is my response XML. I hear "this is a test" and then I hear " h t t p colon slash slash some url". Any idea why  is being ignored and plays out as text to speech instead? Thanks.

```
<Response>
    <Say voice="man" language="en">
        This is a test.
    </Say>
    <Redirect>
        http://SomeURL
    </Redirect>
</Response>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well.. according to the docs of TwiML you are redirecting to TwiML at a different url. TwiML is the Twilio language to handle responses.

Below is pasted from the docs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Redirect method="POST">http://pigeons.com/twiml.xml</Redirect>
</Response>
```

So the redirect should receive some valid TwiML.

Comment: Thanks but the issue is that <Redirect> doesnt even execute the re-direct tag. I have tried valid urls that return valid TwiML but still i hear the actual url playing out in text to speech...

Answer (score 0):

Check that your are returning the proper MIME type.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml#twilio-understands-mime-types

Comment: Thanks. That was indeed the issue. I added the mime type into my Springboot request mapping and it is now working as expected.